# Bike won't start

Tags: honda, motorcycle, starting

I'd like to ask for some advice regarding my problem about my bike. Got a new battery for it, installed it and now my bike won't to start using electric starter, but works fine using kickstart. It turns on but my headlight, tail lights, indicators and horn won't function properly. Before changing my battery, everything works fine. I have checked the +/-  post. Everything looks tight. No issues on the post whatsoever. Been revving it for about 15 minutes to see if the battery would charge. Nothing happened. Had a run for about an hour but still, nothing happened. I'm kinda dumb-founded how this is happening. Anyone knows what's causing this? I'd appreciate any help. And oh, my bike is a Honda XRM 125.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go back and look at all of your connections. Pull everything off the battery and ensure the posts are clean as well as the connectors. Take a wire brush to them and ensure you are seeing fresh metal where the connection comes together. Then trace the wires back to their source and do the same thing. Your problem is pretty classic for where there's no connectivity somewhere. Cleaning the connections should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Check that any large amperage fuses in the battery circuit are ok.